# Как правильно: единодержцам или единодержавцам?

Tags: орфография

Как правильно: единодержцам или единодержавцам?

Comment: А ваше-то мнение какое?

Answer (score 1):

У вас трудности только в дательном множественного?

Вообще-то есть оба слова, ***"единодержец"*** и ***"единодержавец"*** - оба не слишком распространенные, не во всех словарях присутствующие, но в основном синонимичные.

Но вместе с тем, если первое, "единодержец", сомнения не вызывает (=автократ, самодержец - т.е. абсолютный монарх), то второе, "единодержавец", может означать не только самого самодержца, но приверженца такого политического устройства. Так что нужен контекст, особенно в связи с тем, что у вас явно множественное число, а самодержец - он как правило один.

Answer (score 1):

**единодержец**(устар.) - государь, самодержец, божий помазанник, царь, император, скипетродержец, скипетроносец, монарх, **единодержавец**(устар.), венценосец (синонимы).

***единодержец*** - единодержцы(мн.ч., и.п.) - ***единодержцам***(мн.ч., дат.п.);
***единодержавец*** - единодержавцы - ***единодержавцам***.

Правильны оба варианта. Вот только в каком контексте? - хотелось бы видеть.